# Close Bootstrap Modal and show another after ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

in my project I'm Working with Asp core 3.1, I'm saving data with ajax using bootstrap modal and it saves but modal didn't hide in success and I want to show another modal with data feedback it didn't show either it shows dialog with html markup like in picture
[image]
so here is my ajax Code

```
 $('#btnSave').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Add();
});
function Add() {
    var res = Validate();  
    if (res == false) {
        return false;
    }  
   
    var CategoryObj = {
        CategoryName: $("#inputCategory").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Writer/SaveCategory",
        data: JSON.stringify(CategoryObj),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8", 
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            
            $('#NewCategory').modal('hide');

             $("#content").html(result);
            $("#ResultCategory").modal("show");
            $("#ResultCategory").appendTo("body");;
        },  
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }  
    });
}
```

and in  my controller code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveCategory([FromBody]CategoryModelDto categoryModel)
    {
        CategoryModelDto categoryModelDto = new CategoryModelDto();
        if (ModelState.IsValid==true)
        {
            categoryModelDto= await _categoryService.CreateNewCategory(categoryModel);
        }
        
        return PartialView("_CategoryResult", categoryModelDto);
    }
```

and my view

```
<button type="button" id="addCategory" style="margin-left:15px;" class="btn btn-primary">
New Category
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="NewCategory" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="NewCategoryLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div id="modalContent" class="modal-content">

        <partial name="_CreateCategory" model="Model.CategoryModel" />

    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ResultCategory" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ResultCategoryLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div id="content" class="modal-content">
        <partial name="_CategoryResult" model="Model.CategoryModel" />
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

So I need help to get hide the save modal and show another modal with return data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem actually the problem was in one line in ajax code So all the code in controller and the view is correct and the line data type must be deleted the line is

```
 dataType: "json"
```

When I deleted this line the code is working Well Thanks for every one

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close `NewCategory` modal and replace partial view of `ResultCategory` modal when click button which id is `btnSave`,try to use the following code:
ResultCategory modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ResultCategory" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ResultCategoryLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <partial name="_CategoryResult" model="Model.CategoryModel" />
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

js:

```
 $('#btnSave').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#NewCategory').modal('hide');
    Add();
});
function Add() {
    var res = Validate();  
    if (res == false) {
        return false;
    }  
   
    var CategoryObj = {
        CategoryName: $("#inputCategory").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Writer/SaveCategory",
        data: JSON.stringify(CategoryObj),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8", 
        success: function (result) {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = result;
            $("#ResultCategory").modal("show");
        },  
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }  
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes that's what I want and I'm try your answer and it didn't work it HTML markup by dialog and the first modal didn't hide too

Comment: Do you have any error in console?I test with the code,and it can work.

Comment: No i haven't and I run many solutions and still same resullt

Comment: actually I don't know what is wrong to fix